# computing E[X|X>4]

Tags: probability, solution-verification, expectation

Let X be a random variable that takes value of integers from 1 to 10 with equal probability respectively.

I am trying to compute E[X|X>4].

The attempt I made are:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
E[X|X>4] &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}nP(X=n|X>4)\\
&= \sum\limits_{n=5}^{10}nP(X=n|X>4)\\
&=\sum\limits_{n=5}^{10} n P(X=n)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{10}\sum\limits_{n=5}^{10}n\\
&=\dfrac{45}{10}
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

My concern is whether the step $P(X=n|X>4)$ is equivalent to $P(X=n)$ for n larger than 4 onwards?

The other sidenote question;

For $P(X=4|X=5)$, if we expand the above expression, we have by definition:
$\dfrac{P(X=4,X=5)}{P(X=5)}$ and hence, can we say that the expression is zero because for the numerator, it is impossible for X to be 4 and 5 at the same time?

Comment: By definition $P(X=n\mid X>4)=P(X=n,X>4)/P(X>4)$ which is not equal to $P(X=n)$.

Comment: Yes $P(X=4|X=5)=0$.   $P(X=n|X>4)=0$ for $n \le 4$ and $P(X=n|X>4)=\frac{P(X=n)}{\sum_{k=5}^{10} P(X=k)}$ for $n>4$

Comment: I think you can regard $X|X>4$ as a random variable that takes integer values from $5$ to $10$ with equal probability.

Comment: @kmitov: Is it possible to give further hints on how you manage to derive the formula? By definition, I get the part on the denominator where P(X>4)= $\sum\limits_{n=5}^{10}P(X=n)$, does it means that $P(X=n,X>4)= P(X=n)$ because the event for $X=n \subset X>4 $ for n larger than 4?

Comment: yes that is true.

Comment: thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ denote the indicator function, i.e. $I(A)=1$ if $A$ is true and $I(A)=0$ if $A$ is false.  Then

$$E(X|X>4)= \frac{E\bigl( XI(X>4) \bigr)}{P(X>4)}
= \frac{1}{6} \sum_{x=5}^{10} x=\frac{45}{6}=\frac{15}{2}.$$